# UnityEngine.Camera does not contain a definition for allowHDR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

i downloaded a game in unity 5.3.3 and i get this
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdQb5.png)

this is what the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU5DK.png) looks like

can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: The unity docs dont suggest camera has that property.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.